# Display uploaded file or image in grid in php

Tags: php

I have successfully uploaded some images to the server. Im thinking to display them in my admin page in grid view.. currently it displayed vertically. 
Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance for you kind assistance.

```
<?php
$dir_path = "../../img/gallery/";
$extensions_array = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
if(is_dir($dir_path))
{
$files = scandir($dir_path);
for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++)
{
if($files[$i] !='.' && $files[$i] !='..')
{
// get file name
echo "File Name: $files[$i]<br>";
// get file extension
$file = pathinfo($files[$i]);
$extension = $file['extension'];
{
// show image
echo "<img src='$dir_path$files[$i]' style='width:60px;height:80px;'><br> 
</br>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
```

This code works fine but I just don't know to display it in grid or table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by echoing each table part inside the loop:

```
<?php
$dir_path = "../../img/gallery/";
$extensions_array = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
$numCol = 3;
if(is_dir($dir_path))
{
    $files = scandir($dir_path);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++)
    {
        $n = 0;
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>';
        if($files[$i] !='.' && $files[$i] !='..')
        {
            $n ++;

            // get file name
            echo "<td>File Name: $files[$i]<br>";
            // get file extension
            $file = pathinfo($files[$i]);
            $extension = $file['extension'];

            // show image
            echo "<img src='$dir_path$files[$i]' style='width:60px;height:80px;'></td>";

            if($n % $numCol == 0) echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';
    }
}
?>
```

`$numCol` defines how many column must have every table's row.

Also, I removed these `{}` that were useless:

```
$extension = $file['extension'];
{
    // show image
    echo "<img src='$dir_path$files[$i]' style='width:60px;height:80px;'><br> 
    </br>";
}
```

Comment: Hooray... it's work.. thanks a lot friend for your kind help.. Any way I wonder if it can be display like 3 cols and 3 rows..

Comment: @Jadd for your other question, you should follow the same way used here.

Comment: Ok noted.. Thanks